# Can i improve the efficiency of this Matlab function?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have written a matlab function that performs some cpu intensive operations on images. I would like to improve the speed of this function, but cannot think of anymore ways to optimize it. Does anyone know how to further optimise the function below?

```
function imageMedoid(imageList, resizeFolder, outputFolder, x, y)

    % local variables
    medoidImage = zeros([1, y*x, 3]);
    alphaImage = zeros([y x]);
    medoidContainer = zeros([y*x, length(imageList), 3]);

    % loop through all images in the resizeFolder
    for i=1:length(imageList)

        % get filename and load image
        fname = imageList(i).name;
        container = im2double(imread([resizeFolder fname]));

        % load alpha channel, convert to zeros and ones, add to alphaImage
        [~,~,alpha] = imread([resizeFolder fname]);
        alpha = double(alpha) / 255;
        alphaImage = alphaImage + alpha;

        % add (r,g,b) values to medoidContainer and reshape to single line
        medoidContainer(:, i, :) = reshape(container, [y*x 3]);

    end

    % loop through every pixel in medoidContainer
    for i=1:length(medoidContainer)

        % calculate distances between all values for current pixel
        distances = pdist(squeeze(medoidContainer(i,:,1:3)));

        % convert found distances to matrix of distances
        distanceMatrix = squareform(distances);

        % find index of image with the medoid value
        [~, j] = min(mean(distanceMatrix,2));

        % write found medoid value to medoidImage
        medoidImage(1, i, 1:3) = medoidContainer(i, j, 1:3);

    end

    % replace values larger than one in alpha channel
    alphaImage(alphaImage > 1) = 1;

    % reshape image to original proportions
    medoidImage = reshape(medoidImage, y, x, 3);

    % save medoid image
    imwrite(medoidImage, [outputFolder 'medoid.png'], 'Alpha', alphaImage);
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the built-in profiler of MATLAB in order to have a better idea on what are the most time consuming operations and then try to optimize there.

```
Tools -> Open Profiler -> imageMedoid(...)
```

Comment: Exactly. It is a waste of time to ask if a long sequence of commands can be improved in efficiency. Let the profile tool do that work for you, to find the points where you should devote effort.

Comment: @woodchips and zenpoy: Ok, so i used Open Profiler, and `imread` and `squareform` take up a lot of time. However, i don't know how to optimise them any further. Is it possible to replace them with more efficient commands?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
imread([resizeFolder fname])
```

twice in your first for-loop. Call it once as

```
[A,~,alpha] = imread([resizeFolder fname]);
```

This should result in some improvement.

Comment: +1 for the answer, i didn't set this as the answer to my question because i think in general people would benefit more from zenpony's answer, but your answer was more useful to me personally, so thanks!